# Can oxygen shortage in breaths affect the person's voice properties?

Tags: breathing, oxygen, voice

It is both funny and strange, that after hearing this on a movie(which I assumed then, it's been added to make movie sound deeply scientific), about oxygen shortage in successive breaths affect person's voice properties like tone, intensity etc., when I searched for it, I did find that it has been experienced in reality.

So now my curiosity being heightened, I really need to know whether the shortage of breath/oxygen always causes a person's voice to change or it only occurs in some special circumstances ?

Moreover, what is the reason for this to happen ?

My question is based on this: https://pulmonaryhypertensionnews.com/forums/forums/topic/do-you-ever-notice-changes-in-your-voice/

Comment: It would be helpful if you cite sources for your previous research.

Comment: https://pulmonaryhypertensionnews.com/forums/forums/topic/do-you-ever-notice-changes-in-your-voice/ - It might not be fully credible, and that's why I asked the question here

Comment: Seems to be more an aspect of pulmonary hypertension than O2 levels.